# Word order in doubts

Tags: word-order

Let's suppose that there are two people talking each other at a restaurant:

> John: I'll have one hamburger and large soda for lunch.
>
> Sandy: So will I.
>
> John: So you will?

Here, my question is about the order of the agreement in the "Sandy"'s answer. I mean, my doubt is about the word order in this kind of agreement structure.

I would like to know if it's necessary to respect the inversion of the auxiliary verb "will" ("So will you?" ) in statement or I need to change the word order ("So you will"?) in a question grammar mood?

Comment: What is the point of John's response? What is he trying to say? Is he surprised by Sandy's ordering the same thing as he is? As a note, unless you're at a restaurant with tiny burgers, you're unlikely to say "one hamburger"... you just say "a hamburger". You also need an article before "large soda".

Comment: In this case I am applying the parallel structure where it is not necessary to repeat the same article twice because it's the same pronoun which acts.

Comment: We wouldn't use that here, though. The only time I can imagine saying "one hamburger and large soda" is if "hamburger and large soda" is a menu item. In general, if you want two separate menu items, you say "I'll have a burger and a large soda for lunch".

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways to answer with subtle nuances.  As Catija points out, the use of "so" in the "doubt" is unusual but I think not ungrammatical.

The standard way to express surprise at someone's action is to repeat the verb back at them, whether or not they use "so".

> "I'm going to a Donald Trump rally."
>   "So will I."
>   "You will?"
>
> "She's turning 50 tomorrow."
>   "So am I."
>   "You are?"
>
> "They bought over a thousand dollars in toys for their kids"
>   "They did?"

The use of "so" at the start of a statement indicates a kind of *congruity* between what was previously stated and the current statement.  For example:

> "I am going to Washington to protest!"
>   "So will the rest of us!"
>
> "I decided to apply to college, so you should too."

If you use "so" at the start of a doubt, it indicates that you *expect* the person will go along with the previous statement, but you're not sure:

> "I will go to the market this weekend."
>   "I should go with you."
>   "So you will?"
>   "Yeah ... ok I guess I'll go."
>
> "I'm thinking of adopting a cat."
>   "So you will?"
>   "No, I'm just *thinking* about it."

In your example, "So you will?" doesn't make sense unless there was some expectation to go along with the doubt.  John is surprised that Sandy wanted to have the same food he ordered, and while he expects that it is indeed what she will order, there still is some doubt.

As I said, subtle differences.  It's not something you would ordinarily say unless you really understood the nuance.

Comment: Please use quote text, not code markup. There's no formatting here you need to preserve. You can put double spaces at the end of lines to do single carriage returns within a quote block.

Comment: @Catija thanks, didn't know how to conserve line breaks in a quoted block.  Now I do.

Comment: Sure :D It's one of those little things that took me a while to learn, too :D Always glad to help.